# Индексы в mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть такая модель:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  patronymic: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Будет осуществляться поиск по полям name, surname, patronymic (возможно одновременно или по отдельности), то такой индекс мне поможет?

```
userSchema.index({ name: 'text', surname: 'text', patronymic: 'text' });
```